# How do you specify the key size of a Certificate Signing Request?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl

I'm trying to generate a CSR with godaddy. I used the following commands to create the certificate:

```
openssl req -new -nodes -keyout server.key -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
```

But when I use the key generated in my server.csr file, I get the following error from godaddy:

```
The CSR key length must be 2048 or 4096
```

How do I specify the key size of the CSR?

P.S. I'm intending to use this on a domain hosted on heroku.

Comment: I'm not familiar with OpenSSL, but it's not the CSR that needs to be 2048 bits, it's the Private Key that the CSR is generated for that needs to be 2048.

Comment: Ok, I think that's what I mean. It's telling me that the CSR key length is not the right length.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should work for you:

> openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout your.key -out your.csr

-newkey rsa:size - type and size of the private key

Answer (score 2):

The way i prefer to do this is to edit the openssl.cfg and change the "default_bits" to "2048". In this way all keys you create will automatically start at the right size

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the cypher type and key length with the -newkey parameter:

```
openssl req -new -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -out server.csr
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but a little more explanation about what is going on here would have been better.